# Overridden attribute properties appear twice in IntelliSense parameter info

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, custom-attributes

I have custom base and derived attribute classes defined as follows:

```
class BaseAttribute : Attribute
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

class DerivedAttribute : BaseAttribute
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I start typing `[Derived(`, the parameter info box that pops up in Visual Studio shows the `Name` property twice for some reason:

[image]

I would only expect `[Name = string]` to appear once. Is this an IDE/IntelliSense bug? Is there anything I can do to fix it (so that the property only appears once)? Here's the version info from the About box:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.6.01038
```